# Matlab - Mark specific points

Tags: matlab, plot

I've a graph given by the set of vectors              {Time1Vector,Height1Vector,Time2Vector,Height2Vector,Time3Vector,Height3Vector} 
which are ploted using:

```
plot(Time1Vector,Height1Vector,'g',Time2Vector,Height2Vector,'b',Time3Vector,Height3Vector,'r');
```

The plot: [image]

I would like to mark the points where the graph change color, or really, where the Time/Height-data changes from 1 to 2 and 2 to 3. How can I accomplish this whitout having to make them stationary (The input-data is asked for in the beginning of the code so the points can't be fixed).

Comment: Since you have the Time and Height vectors, I assume you know when and where the data changes in the plot, even if its dynamic from run to run. Once you have the coordinates of where the color change occurs, you can use the functions/commands in: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/adding-text-annotations-to-graphs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just plot points over the end points of each of your vectors:

eg

```
plot(Time1Vector,Height1Vector,'g',Time2Vector,Height2Vector,'b',Time3Vector,Height3Vector,'r');
hold on
plot(Time1Vector(end),Height1Vector(end),'k^','markerfacecolor',[1 0 0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how to mark points in a basic matlab plot

```
x= 0:0.001:pi;
y= sin(x);
z = (y<0.9);
z1 = (y>0.4);
z = xor(z,z1);
plot(x,y);hold on
plot(x(z),y(z),'o')
```

[image]